# OpenCV SURF for live streaming from webcam in Python

Tags: python, opencv, surf

I am working on surf implementation in opencv using python which will detect the template in the given image. I have modified the code such that it will take video capture from the webcam connected and convert into images and then apply surf on it. Following is the modified code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):

        ret ,img = cap.read()

# Convert them to grayscale
        imgg =cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# SURF extraction
    surf = cv2.SURF()
    kp, descritors = surf.detect(imgg,None,useProvidedKeypoints = False)

# Setting up samples and responses for kNN
    samples = np.array(descritors) 
    responses = np.arange(len(kp),dtype = np.float32)

# kNN training
    knn = cv2.KNearest()
    knn.train(samples,responses)

# Now loading a template image and searching for similar keypoints
    template = cv2.imread('template.png')
    templateg= cv2.cvtColor(template,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    keys,desc = surf.detect(templateg,None,useProvidedKeypoints = False)

    for h,des in enumerate(desc):
            des = np.array(des,np.float32).reshape((1,128))
            retval, results, neigh_resp, dists = knn.find_nearest(des,1)
            res,dist =  int(results[0][0]),dists[0][0]

            if dist<0.1: # draw matched keypoints in red color
                color = (0,0,255)
            else:  # draw unmatched in blue color
                print dist
                color = (255,0,0)

    #Draw matched key points on original image
            x,y = kp[res].pt
            center = (int(x),int(y))
            cv2.circle(img,center,2,color,-1)

    #Draw matched key points on template image
            x,y = keys[h].pt
            center = (int(x),int(y))
            cv2.circle(template,center,2,color,-1)

    cv2.imwrite('img',img)
    cv2.imwrite('tm',template)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
cap.release()
```

But the error which is coming is
       knn.train(samples,responses)
       TyepError:  data type = 17 is not supported

Does anybody have any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

CV probably expects regular arrays but you are passing numpy arrays instead. Try this

```
knn.train(samples.tolist(),responses.tolist())
```

Comment: The error still persisits.`TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array`